# PHP POST: Setting data variables dynamically from an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Hi all I'm pretty new to PHP and AJAX and all that good stuff and I'm a little stumped on how to proceed from  here in my code.

I have a form that is getting sent and I have an array (subcategories) which contains the form labels to retrieve the values of the fields. The fields and values are getting created dynamically based on a textfile that the user uploads so I don't have any way of knowing what they are.

```
var arrayLength = subcategories.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var eachfield = subcategories[i];
  //Do something

  //@C: selector is working fine, cleaning input
  var eachfield = $('#' + eachfield).val().trim();

  //push the appropriate values with the fixed stuff to a new array
  values.push(eachfield);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is now to set these variables to some name and send them through $data using AJAX and POST.

Something like the following if I was setting everything statically.

```
var data = {
  dimitypedata: dimitype,
  densitydata: density,
  velocitydata: velocity,
  temperaturedata: temperature,

  submitbtnclicked: "submitted"
};

//using the data and sending it through a post with promise handling
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "controller.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
    //alert("worked");
    //console.log(response);
    alert(response);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("There was an error submitting the information");
  }
});
```

I'm not quite sure how to mix these two and it may be partially because of getting a confused and not yet being that great with POST and AJAX calls.

EDIT: It looks like my question was a bit unclear (sorry first post lol) I'm trying to dynamically push values that I take out of an HTML form field. The problem is that the form is generated depending on what the user chooses to upload to the site (so both the fields and the forms. My ultimate goal is to enable the user to edit the dynamically generated form based on a text file that they upload and be able to generate a new text file after editing it on the GUI after clicking on the submit button. I can do this if its static but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the same if I don't know what the form will contain.

I'm trying to to my data object so I can use it in my AJAX call. Here's a little bit of the PHP code that I would use in the next step if the variables were static:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbtnclicked']) && $_POST['submitbtnclicked'] == 'submitted') {
//new instance of model for use
    $model = new model();

$dimitypedata = $_POST['dimitypedata'];
$densitydata = $_POST['densitydata'];
$velocitydata = $_POST['velocitydata'];
$temperaturedata = $_POST['temperaturedata'];
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? We need to know how to help.

Comment: First your PHP code? Second what type of data you expect to receive from your php?

Comment: @Kyle I edited the question to make it a bit more clear. The problem is that because the form is generated dynamically I don't know what the fields and the values will be (or how much of them there will be) so I need a way to push them to the dynamically generated data object. I know how to do so statically but because the form is generated dynamically the object should be too and that's where I get lost.

Comment: @JoseMarques Not exactly my first no but I haven't had to deal with too many dynamic things in mine before. I'm trying to extract some text/number values from a form and make them into a new text file. I edited my question to maybe help make it a bit clear.

Comment: If I understand, you want to send multiple values ​​in your array via ajax?

Comment: @JoseMarques I was basically ((read: confused)) trying to dynamically make my data object to use it in my AJAX call. Someone answered the question and now everything makes so much more sense with the answer in front of me. Thank you so much for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an exact answer, we need to see what the "subcategories" array look like.

If I understood correctly, you would like to put the values in an object instead of an array (values). So the first part would look like:

```
var data = {};
var arrayLength = subcategories.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    //notice that now field name and field value go in separate variables
    var fieldName = subcategories[i];

    //@C: selector is working fine, cleaning input
     var fieldValue = $('#'+eachfield).val().trim();

     //push the appropriate values with the fixed stuff to a data object
     data[fieldName] = fieldValue;
}


//and then you send your gathered data
//using the data and sending it through a post with promise handling
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "controller.php",
 data: data, 
 success: function(response) {
     //alert("worked");
     //console.log(response);
     alert(response);
   },
   error: function() {
        alert("There was an error submitting the information");
      }
 });
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe the solution was that simple! I feel a little dumb. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate your 'data' object using 'values' variable, you can do the next:

```
values = []; // here your values collected previously
var data = {};
for (var key in values){
    data[key] = values[key];
}
//now you can use your data in AJAX
```